# I can't take input form user properly

Tags: c

I can't take inputs as I want. `gets()` doesn't work properly. If I put n = 3, it always get total `5` input as a string. why not `6`?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>

int main()

{
    int n;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    char a[n][105], b[n][105];

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        gets(a[i]);

        gets(b[i]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never ever use `gets`. Google "why is gets dangerous" to find out why.

Comment: "gets doesn't work properly" is certainly true. That's why it has been removed from the language.  Don't use it.

Comment: If your input is "n = 3", I would expect the first scanf to fail and n remain uninitialized.  What is your actual input?  Is it "3\ntext\ntext\n"? Or "3 text..."? or "3text", or "357"? What do you mean by "total 5 input as a string"?

Comment: What do you mean by "it always get total 5"?

Comment: "why not 6?" Why 6?

Comment: I think, when i=0, it should take two inputs a[0],b[0]. after i =1, a[1], b[1], after i=2, a[2],b[2]. total 6 @WilliamPursell

Comment: don't mix `fgets()` (or the non-existent `gets()`) with `scanf()`. Better to stick with `fgets()` for user input.

Comment: Your program does that.  If your input is correct.  eg `printf "3foo\nbar\nbaz\nqux\nquux\nquuz\n" | ./a.out` does what you want.  But perhaps you are incorrectly using some other input.  So the question remains: what is your input?

Comment: I would guess you are using input `3\nfooo...` and the extra newline is causing your first `gets` (ew, I get chills just writing that) is reading a blank line.